# Update cached data with real time updates

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I'm currently working on an android app and I'm using firestore as my storage method. There is a feature in my app that, after a user selects a city, It downloads all it's stores. Given that those stores do not change often, I'm using a flag to know if the stores from one city had been downloaded before, so that I can use cached data instead of server data. My problem is that, if the info of a store changes, a store is added or a store is deleted, the only way the user can get the updated data is to "force download" the city again.

I would like to add a real time listener for a city instead of force downloading. The thing here is that I don't know that, for example, if I have all the stores in cache and suddenly the store "ABCD"  changes and triggers my snapshot listener, will it update my cache data as well? If not, is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a listener active for the documents of interest that might change, then nothing will change in your local cache.  You simply must have that listener active in order to get changes to documents as they happen, and that will cost document reads.

Consider using Firebase Cloud Messaging from your backend to tell your app when data has changed, and it can query that data as needed.  That will be a fair amount of work to set up.

Comment: So, are you saying that if I first made a "one time" download for all my stores, and then I create a real time listener in those documents, cache will be updated if my listener is triggered?

Also, I removed my second question.

Comment: Yes, the cache will be kept up to date as long as the listener is active.  But the subsequent listener will also cost document reads for each matched document on the first iteration.  So if you're trying to reduce document reads, it could be kind of costly for large collections.  You will probably want a way to determine which documents are new or changed, using a timestamp or something.